# When using .NET Core for cross platform development, can I be sure that my program will be consistent across platforms?

Tags: c#, .net-core, cross-platform

I'm basically asking if I need to test my program on all the platforms I am targeting, or if I can be confident that it will run on any platform if it runs on my windows machine.

Comment: Some APIs won't work and will throw a PlatformNotSupported Exception. Others *could* behave differently due to the use of different underlying native implementations. So yeah, I'd say you'd want to test it out

Comment: Yes, you should always test. Never make assumptions (or accept that you may be wrong)